# Angular ui-grid - CSS to center the text in the columns so both lines are centered

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

How do I configure Angular UI-grid to center the columns so both lines are centered?

I define the `headerCellClass: text-c` and `width: 98`, in `grid.columnDefs` like this:

```
{
     name: 'TotalOutstanding',
     displayName: 'Total Outstanding',
     width: 98,
     type: 'number',
     cellClass: 'text-c',
     headerCellClass: 'text-c'
}
```

and `text-c` in css file like this:

```
.text-c {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But I get the result in image attached.

I really need both words to be centered. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the class `.ui-grid-cell-contents` has set `white-space: nowrap;`
If you change that to normal it will work, so your css should look like this:

```
.text-c .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

According to your setup (`cellClass: 'text-c', headerCellClass: 'text-c'`), this css will affect the header as well as the cells..

**--- EDIT ---**
According to comments by the OP, that the original answer did not work for him, I added a comment that did help him. I'm adding that comment to the answer here below:

I think that the sorting icon position is affecting you.
I took the Plunker from UI-Grid's tutorials ([Tutorial: 115 HeaderCellClass](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20115%20HeaderCellClass)), and edited it to fit your scenario.
I used the header cell class `ui-grid-header-cell-label` to change the display to `inline-block` so it will "push" the sort icon to the next line: [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0S3BssE0pOuADM5cGKN?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you- however that does not seem to work for me.  There must be another way to do this

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work. I think that the sorting icon position is affecting you.  

I took the Plunker from UI-Grid's tutorials (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20115%20HeaderCellClass),  
and edited it to fit your scenario (used the header cell class `ui-grid-header-cell-label` to change the display to `inline-block` so it will "push" the sort icon to the next line): http://plnkr.co/edit/j0S3BssE0pOuADM5cGKN?p=preview

Comment: That seems to work well - Thank you for taking the time with this!

Comment: Great to hear that, I will edit my answer with it and I would appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer for the community..